# TypeScript : How to fix TS7016 : Type definition not found 404

Tags: typescript

I am new in react, and I've been doing a project with `Flow`. Last night i met `TypeScript`. It's awesome.

I've decided to migrate to `TypeScript` from `Flow` and have been converting my `.js/.jsx` files to `.ts/.tsx`. I've installed type definitions for `react, redux etc` It works perfectly fine. But , I can't find type definition for a library called `react-native-material-color`. It's not a famous library. I am getting below error.

[image]

and when i try to install the typedef using npm , am getting 404

[image]

1. How can i fix the error ?
2. Is there any option to tell TypeScript to skip the type check for a
   specific library ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can fix the error by writing typings yourself, or preferably by installing the types (if they do exist) using `npm install --save-dev @types/react-native-material-color`.
2. You can require the implementation without importing the typings like so:

**Example:**

```
const Color = require("react-native-material-color");
```

Comment: They don't exist. So i'll go with the option 2. Thanks @Jamie

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
// @ts-ignore
import Color from "react-native-material-color"
```